# Columns valorization in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

this is my situation

1st table:

| id |
| --- |
| 012 |
| 345 |
| 678 |

2nd table:

| id | flag |
| --- | --- |
| 012 | A |
| 345 | B |
| 678 | C |

I need to use the ids as a key in order to obtain something like that:

| id | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 012 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 345 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 678 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: valorize is not a term I've ever heard before for this. Dummy coding is a common term, or parameterization. Just a note that many SAS procedures do not require you to parameterize your variables before regression, you specify them as CLASS variables.

Comment: This post shows a few different ways of accomplishing this: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/How-to-create-dummy-variables-Categorical-Variables/ta-p/308484

Answer (score 2):

SAS know a lot about dummy variables.

```
data have;
   infile cards expandtabs;
   input id:$3. flag:$1.;
   cards;
012 A
345 B
678 C
;;;;
proc print;
proc transreg data=have design;
   model class(flag / zero=none);
   output out=coded;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

Answer (score 1):

From your example there's no requirement for Table 1 to be used that I can see. If there is a need, you'll need to modify your example to show how it's relevant.

Otherwise, a quick and dirty way:

- Use PROC FREQ to generate the counts and set them as 1 and 0s
- Transpose to desired data structure
- If you just need displayed output, the PROC FREQ step is enough

```
proc freq data=have ;
table id*flag / sparse out=long nopercent norow nocol;
run;


proc transpose data=long out=want (drop = _:);
by id;
id flag;
var count;
run;
```